# Substring Matching with Sheets API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using google-spreadsheet for handling my spreadsheet online. Here is an npm link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet

This module provides an option to send a structured query but i can not seem to find out how to do substring matching through a structured query. Queries like 
"A like '%ba'", "A = '%ba'" don't work and returns null rows. I have tried doing it through simple GET requests as well but i can not find out where my query will go into the url and where my api key will go in the url.

TL:DR;
I want to do substring matching through sheets API.

Comment: Can you try this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)? I think it uses substrings as well although not NodeJS implementation (but still Javascript).

Comment: This is not for Spreadsheets.